# How do I succeed at the IT internship?

Tags: career-development, it

I'm a 34 years old, and I've recently completed graduate certificate in engineering last semester in Australia, and I am planning to take a part-time internship in IT while working in the evening.

I'm struggling with socializing because I'm an introvert and I find it difficult to connect with people. This is something I want to overcome because I want to be successful in the internship.

How can I build an effective and professional working relationship?
Any advice is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is way too general. What is it that you struggle with and need help with? Just saying socialising doesn't really give us anything to go off of and could be a lot of different things. The good news is you'll probably meet other introverted people and will be able to pick up on how they manage the office space. This is common in IT and more likely than not you'll see someone that barely interacts with the rest of the team and you can then decide how much interaction you think is manageable. It is not necessarily a requirement to be successful either. Maybe ask for a mentor as well?

Comment: Basically, I feel anxious every time I'm having a conversation and at my work I usually don't talk much to my coworkers.

Comment: That will pass as you get to know these people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Internships are for learning. Ask a lot of questions and bring a positive attitude to work and the socializing will take care of itself.
2. Lots of people like to talk about their work, so asking a lot of questions about work topics is usually enough to get people going. When they mention non-work interests, ask follow-up questions about those topics, if appropriate.
3. If you are genuinely interested in other people, they will think very highly of you, it's just natural. You will get invited to more "off-work" functions and should try to go, even just for a coffee.
4. Don't try too hard. Read Ali Abdaal's "Feel-Good Productivity", where he explores the idea of just doing 1 thing for your goals.

Comment: You can also talk about non-work topics, but be careful.  Show the people you care about them, e.g. if someone mentions there mom had surgery on Monday, ask how she is on Tuesday.

Comment: Thank you guys.

Comment: @StephenMelbenCorral You are very welcome! If this was helpful to you, please consider accepting the answer. :)